# VIM CINO not working as expected

Tags: vim

I have searched high-and-low for the answer to this question, and have had no luck.  I moved away from an integrated development environment to using VIM.  (I've been very happy about it, too!)  Most of my code is written in C.

I cannot seem to get my cindent options to work correctly.  I want my indent levels to be set at 4 space, but no matter what I do, I get eight spaces.

I have tried a number of different options, without success.  Here are what I believe are the applicable settings from my .vimrc:

```
" Set options for c program formatting
set cindent
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set smartindent
set cino=>4,e4,n4,^4,:4,=4
set colorcolumn=81
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? (In case it matters, the other plugins that I am using are crefvim, c.vim, minibufexplorer, and cscope_maps).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of the various C indent options.  Almost all of the values that can be set on cino to modify the indentation are described in the [vim manual](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values%27) as "Add N to the *prevailing* indent" under certain circumstances. (Emphasis mine)

You're getting 8 space indentation because you've told vim that you want a standard indent of 4 spaces (via `:set sw=4`) and then, for example, you've told cindent that you want another 4 spaces of indentation inside of any braces which appear in the first column (via `:set cino=^4`).

I loaded your settings, minus the cino bit, into a clean vim.  I got plain-vanilla, four-space-indent C formatting thereafter.

Comment: Thank you Lief, you were absolutely correct.  I commented out the cino options and it worked just fine.  I must have read the vim manual a dozen times and *still* did not pick up on this.  ...And I consider myself an educated person.  Thank you, again.

Comment: @ipersuade Glad I could help.  Happy Vimming!

Comment: @ipersuade If you think I answered your question, would you be willing to mark my answer as having solved your problem?

Comment: You certainly DID answer my question.  Thank you, again.